# Dynamically place fragments in a table layout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have a little problem. I have a n number of fragments and i want to put this fragments in a row, but when the screen runs out, the rest goes to the bottom line, and so on.

I'm doing this:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
        PresencaFragment aFragment = new PresencaFragment("Test "+i, "2017059227_11.jpg", 2017000000);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag, aFragment).commit();
    }
```

And the code of my fragment and home fragment (i put this n fragments in home fragment) is:

HomeFragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHoras"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="A carregar dados..."
        android:textColor="@color/corescola"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frag"
            >

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my fragment code's:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PresencaFragment">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="264dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="252dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:stretchColumns="1">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="#7EC5CAE9"
                android:minHeight="55dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_nomeAluno"
                    android:layout_width="378dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:width="300dp"
                    android:text="Student Name"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#eee"
                android:minHeight="35dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_numero"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:width="300dp"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="Student number: xxxxxxxxx"

                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#eee"
                android:minHeight="35dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imagem"
                    android:layout_width="371dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            </TableRow>


        </TableLayout>

    </TableLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

So, i want this but obtain this:

[image of what i want and what i obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQsjk.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `R.id.frag` when starting a fragment. As far as I see, the `R.id.frag` is the ID of the whole table layout, which means you're replacing whole table with the fragment. What you want is to set each fragment in the correct row id.

Note: having fragments in the table is really a bad practice. If you need a table layout, you should use views within it, check some tutorial about it, like this: https://abhiandroid.com/ui/tablelayout